# Official list for PageMap/DataObject tags and values for rich snippets?

Tags: seo, google, rich-snippets, xml, headers

To help search engines (like google) in generating "rich results" for your site, you can add a PageMap in the form of commented html-ish markup in your .

But how to know all the useful name-value that a search engine would use and would render as rich result?
Is there an official list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's official list of all the rich snippets that you can get is called the "search gallery":

#### [Explore the Search Gallery and Rich Results  |  Documentation  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/search-gallery)

When you say "PageMap/DataObject tags" I think you are referring to "structured data". The official site for all structured data is [Schema.org](https://schema.org/docs/schemas.html). However, using most structured data will not lead to a rich snippet. It has to be listed in the search gallery for there to be a rich snippet associated with it.